# How to convert this PHP Regular Expression to a Javascript Regular Expression?

Tags: php, javascript, regex

**Here is my PHP regex:**

```
if(preg_match('/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+\n){3}$/', $all_questions))
{
    //Code here
}
```

**And this is how I am trying to convert it to Javascript:**

```
if(fullString.match('/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+\n){3}$/'))
{
    //Code here
}
```

Although, the regex language between PHP and Javascript is slightly different, and I am not to sure how to convert it from PHP to Javascript.

Here is an example of what I am trying to validate:

```
question1,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4
question2,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4
question3,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4
```

I need to validate that exact format, being:

```
string[comma]string[comma]string[comma]string[comma]string[linebreak]
string[comma]string[comma]string[comma]string[comma]string[linebreak]
string[comma]string[comma]string[comma]string[comma]string[linebreak]
```

Each line will ALWAYS have 5 strings and 4 commas, never more and never less.

This is how my PHP preg_match looks:

```
if(preg_match('/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+\n){3}$/', $fullString))
{
    //Code here
}
```

Could someone give me a hand on converting it to a Javascript regex?

Greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @brasofilo - Yes, that was my previous question. All commenters were getting off-topic and off-discussion from the question. This was unfair to me and my question.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - Like so? - `if(fullString.test(/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+\n){3}$/))` Because by removing the quotes, I get an error...

Comment: Sorry, but duplicating your own Question is not aceptable. Improve the previous one. Write a good Q at the very start, so you'll avoid downvotes.

Comment: `if(/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+\n){3}$/.test(fullString))`

Comment: RegExp in javascript are objects with their own set of functions where you can pass strings into

Comment: @Hless is right - I should have clarified what I meant.

Comment: @Hless - Unfortunately, that is not returning the same result as my PHP regex. Does something need to be changed within the regex so that it works correctly within Javascript since it was originally created for PHP?

Comment: @fizzix could you show us an example where they don't return the same thing?

Comment: Can you give us a string to work with? I'm not sure what the input string looks like. Also define what you are trying to capture or match in the input string

Comment: @Hless - Added an example

Comment: @fizzix could it be the case that your JS string does not have the trailing `\n` but your PHP string does?

Comment: @m.buettner - It definitely has the `\n` after each line. I know this since I have tested to print each string out and they are both identical.

Comment: @fizzix then it must be something else in your code. I get a match with Hless's snippet and your given input string

Comment: @fizzix you have included the PHP code twice now

Comment: Try this: `/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+[^.]){3}$/` and see if that gives you a match, if it does indeed give you a match. It is definitely an issue with \n character.

Comment: f you don't have a trailing ``\n`` character, I don't think it'll match (at least in JavaScript).

Comment: @m.buettner - Thank you for that. Found an error on how my string was being built in Javascript. All working now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Hless - Your first snippet worked great. Was another error in my code not adding on the trailing `\n`. It is now working great!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a string in javascript. You can simply use a regular expression object:

```
str.match(/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+\n){3}$/);
```

You can try it out for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/mBb4S/

Also, MDN has some decent information on regular expressions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: In an `if` expression, `test` would actually suffice.